Large text data making remote query extremely slow
I have a table that has a column that stores html in a text column.
The database is remote.  If I try to say pull the first 500 records with the html column it will take 25 minutes for the query to complete but the analyze shows it executing fast:

So this leads me to think that it's to do with the transfer.  It looks like it is quite large records:

20mb is quite large but taking 25 minutes seems like I have things configured wrong seeing as all servers involved are powerful with a lot of bandwidth.
I need to be able to receive this data fast.
What can I do?
Edit:  If I ssh into the server and run in terminal the query completes immediately.  A single record is about 100k and takes almost 30 seconds to query remotely.  Why does this amount of data take so long over a remote connection?  There has to be a way to make the transfer data quicker
Edit:  I failed to mention that postgresql is running in a docker container on the server
Edit: This is speedtest run inside container

Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 1830.62 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 1321.51 Mbit/s


Please post the code as text, not screenshot.

The query is not the issue, I am showing results of the explain.  This is conceptual issue with a large field data that takes very long time to query remotely.  The image shows data is large but query is quick

Pretty obvious your bandwidth is not what you think it is. Do an scp(or equivalent)  of a large file from the server and see what the speed is.

if you are using PostgreSQL 17 already (probably not, but...), please try EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, SERIALIZE) .... it will add time of deTOAST to EXPLAIN ANALYZE output.

@AdrianKlaverI can download several GB in the time it takes me to get a single 100k record from the same server

@RabbanKeyak I am using 16.4

What query finished immediately over ssh?  The EXPLAIN ANALYZE, or the real query which sends the 20MB back over the tunnel?

Maybe the problem is the unknown GUI you are using.  What happens if you use psql, with \copy to run the query?

@jjanes the real query, i can see the data

@jjanes I have tried remoteley using psql.exe, npgsql driver (in code), pgadmin and datagrip.  All have same slow query speed when run remotely.

Over ssh, does the data itself appear immediately, or are you just looking at a time computed on the remote side and reported back to you, and see that that reported time is low?

Try running a query with a limit of 100 and 1000. If the request takes 2 times longer for 1000 and 5 times faster for 100, most likely the main time is spent on transmission over the network.

It seems the docker node was not getting restarted when I thought it was.  Restarting the node has dramatically increased the speed.
I am not sure why it slowed down so much, I am guessing it must be a config setting.
